# httpd service starting although it is disabled to start on reboot

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, rhel7, pacemaker

I'm using RHEL 7.4 OS. I have done `systemctl disable httpd.service` to disable auto start of httpd. It is disabled also.

`[root@clustermrfc002 ~]# systemctl is-enabled httpd
disabled`.

But on reboot httpd service is starting.

`Jul 28 18:02:07 clustermrfc002.novalocal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 28 18:02:08 clustermrfc002.novalocal httpd[8732]: [Sat Jul 28 18:02:08.357617 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8732] AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use
Jul 28 18:02:08 clustermrfc002.novalocal systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.`

which is causing problem in rhel 7 pacemaker cluster, below error is seen.

```
Jul 28 18:12:23 clustermrfc001 pengine[7420]:    error: Resource MNGT_httpd_rhcdDaemon (systemd::httpd) is active on 2 nodes attempting recovery
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of "chkconfig" and review its runlevel.
Or, check if any other service for HTTPD is enabled using "systemctl list-unit-files", if enabled, disable and verify

Answer (score 0):

Although httpd.service is disabled to start on boot, its started by network.target as a dependency.

```
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network.
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility...
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
Jul 26 15:02:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting 
The Apache HTTP Server...
```